# Find and sort list

Tags: c++, list, sorting, dictionary

So I have a list of 2 columns like this:

```
2834    2
2934    1
2712    1
2834    3
2889    1
2659    1
2934    1
2760    1
2173    1
2834    1
2760    1
2834    2
```

The first column is an item ID and the second column is the quantity of that item that is purchased, the price of each item is in another file. What I need to do is find the total quantity of each item ordered, multiply it by its price and then display the top five items by revenue. 
So for example, above 2834 is ordered 8 times, the price of it is $2 so the total revenue for 2834 is $16. How do I find all the occurrences (quantity) of one item, save it's quantity and ID number somewhere, and do the same for the other items without repeating for a previous item. I was told maps would be useful here but I don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a map where the key is the ID number and the value is the quantity:

```
std::map<int, int> quantities;
```

Loop through your list and update the corresponding entry in the map. You can use the `[]` operator on the map to access the value corresponding to a given key. For example, if you had an ID and the quantity from your data, you could do this:

```
quantities[id] += quantity;
```

That works without having to initialize the map because if the `[]` operator asks for an entry that doesn't yet exist in the map, it's automatically inserted with a default value, and the default value for `int` is zero.

Now, you can go through the map and find the prices of all your items. The map's iterator gives you a `pair`, where the first element is the map's key and the second element is the value for that key. You can write a loop like this to print the map's contents:

```
for (std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = quantities.begin();
    it != quantities.end();
    ++it)
{
  std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

If you find the price for each item and multiply it by `it->second`, you'll have what you're looking for.

Comment: this is awesome. How can i get the quantity value from the map. Is it just quantities[ID]? Will that return the quantity for that particular item?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, Richard.

Answer (score 1):

A std::map would be useful - it's basically an array that's indexed by keys.  In your case, the item ID would be the key.  Normally you just put an element in a map with:

```
myMap[key] = value;
```

So for example, assuming readFromFile() fills in id and qty:

```
// Declare a map that uses an int as a key, and an int as a value
std::map<int, int> myMap;

while (readFromFile(&id, &qty))
{
    myMap[id] += qty;
}
```

The first time through, the [] will create the element.  To iterate through the final list you can use standard iterators on a map, just like other STL containers.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a struct `product` to hold the information about each item.  The struct would hold the `ID`, `quantity`, and `price`.
You would make a `std::map<int, product>` where the index is the item's `ID`.
You would read in the price file, and for each line, make a new `product` with that `ID` and price, and then add it to your map, with the `ID` as the index.
You would then read in the sales file, and for each line, get the `product` by reference from the map by the `ID`, and add the number to the `quantity`.
Finally, you would iterate through the map, and write out each `ID`, and the `quantity` ordered multiplied by the `price`.

Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a relational database set up.
One table will have records like [Item_ID, Quantity].
Another table will have records like [Item_ID, Price].

Your task, should you choose to accept it, is to create two tables one for each file.  Use the Item_ID in the first table to find the quantity.  Use the Item_ID into the second table to find the price.  Multiply these two variables to determine the total cost for the Item_ID:

```
unsigned int quantity = Quantity_Table[Item_ID];
double price = Price_Table[Item_ID];
double cost = price * quantity;
```

Start by researching the `std::map` data structure.  Also search Stack Overflow for "while getline c++" to find out how to read files.